# running freebsd on linode

Tags: freebsd, linode

How do I setup a linode to run FreeBSD? There is an example for NetBSD and references to successful attempts at getting FreeBSD to run but no actual document I can find.

Comment: I would suggest marking an answer (IMO, the one from tasaro), for future visitors.

Answer (score 10):

We do not officially support *BSD, but we do have some users who have it running successfully.  Please see http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/BSD_Howto for more info.

Comment: Link broken, cannot find any article Mentioning BSD either.

Answer (score 2):

Linode, from my understanding, don't run FreeBSD straight out of the control panel as an option.

I've personally only used the Ubuntu or Debian images when I've been doing things with them, but from the FAQ, it would appear that you can roll your own distro onto a VPS via uploading it and running through the distro wizard.

It might pay to contact Linode themselves (via email or even scanning the wiki) and see if they've got a FreeBSD option that they're testing (and might be willing to roll out for you) or ask how to carry out that upload/wizard process.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [pretty good guide](http://www.hungryhacker.com/os/freebsd-on-linode/) to getting this working but it seems to unstable to even bother with.

Answer (score 1):

Been a few years since the question was asked, but just in case anyone comes across the question, there's a guide for installing FreeBSD on a Linode:

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/install-freebsd-on-linode